# Does an Animated page title hinder SEO?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I have a client request to animate the title of a web document. Kind of like you can see [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/animatedtitle.htm).

I can make it happen that's no problem, but my questions are:

- Will animating the title cause any issues with the SEO of the page?
- Should I have the final title already in place before I clear and animate the replacement?(my thought is that engines would read and indexed that first before the animation changes it)
- Any other issues i should be worried about regarding SEO?

Comment: Yes you should have the title in the static HEAD section. Then animate title and you wont have any SEO issue.

Comment: You might consider telling your clients that gimmicks like that look incredibly unprofessional...

Comment: I agree with the incredibly unprofessional gimmick, and I have expressed that to the client. But unfortunately, as they say the client is always right and they are the ones signing the check. So.. you know how that story ends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial title (as defined in the HTML) will be what is captured by search engines. So, as long as that's the title you want search engines to see, it won't be a problem. Search engines do not execute the JavaScript on your page (including that which is responsible for animating your title), so they will not capture the animated titles.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I thought. Just needed to hear it from someone else. Cheers!